# How to read value from GPIO port of an ARM microcontroller?

Tags: c, embedded, arm

How do get ARM microcontroller port value into a 32 bit variable.

I am using LPC2378 microcontroller.

Comment: Which device are you using?  The GPIOs aren't part of the ARM core, they're accessed via some other system-on-chip peripheral.

Comment: The header file(s) which come with your compiler will contains declarations for all of the microcontroller's registers, and the bits in those registers. Refer to the reference manual for what all the registers and bits do, and look at some examples. Both can be found here: http://www.keil.com/dd/chip/4153.htm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to access the GPIO registers just like you would any other special function registers in the chip.  The LPC2378 docs show these details:

```
#define GPIO_BASE  0xE0028000
#define IOPIN0     (GPIO_BASE + 0x00) // Port 0 value
#define IOSET0     (GPIO_BASE + 0x04) // Port 0 set 
#define IODIR0     (GPIO_BASE + 0x08) // Port 0 direction
#define IOCLR0     (GPIO_BASE + 0x0C) // Port 0 clear
#define IOPIN1     (GPIO_BASE + 0x10) // Port 1 value
#define IOSET1     (GPIO_BASE + 0x14) // Port 1 set
#define IODIR1     (GPIO_BASE + 0x18) // Port 1 direction
#define IOCLR1     (GPIO_BASE + 0x1C) // Port 1 clear
```

I like to use this macro to access memory-mapped registers:

```
#define mmioReg(a) (*(volatile unsigned long *)(a))
```

Then the code to read the port looks like this:

```
unsigned long port0 = mmioReg(IOPIN0); // Read port 0
unsigned long port1 = mmioReg(IOPIN1); // Read port 1
```

The same macro works for accessing the set/clear/direction registers.  Examples:

```
mmioReg(IOSET1) = (1UL << 3);   // set bit 3 of port 1
mmioReg(IOCLR0) = (1UL << 2);   // clear bit 2 of port 0
mmioReg(IODIR0) |= (1UL << 4);  // make bit 4 of port 0 an output
mmioReg(IODIR1) &= ~(1UL << 7); // make bit 7 of port 1 an input
```

In a real system, I'd normally write some macros or functions for those operations, to cut down on the magic numbers.

Comment: There is probably a header file available for the LPC2378 (provided by the chip maker, NXP, or perhaps by the compiler company) that provides all these for you.

Comment: I can't understand this part: (*(volatile unsigned long *)(a)). Please help me out.

Comment: @AkhilPOommen, what don't you understand?

Comment: hey, plz tell me the difference btw: (1.) #define newreg    (GPIO_addr) (2.) unsigned long *newreg = (GPIO_addr) (3.)  unsigned long *newreg = (unsigned long *)(GPIO_addr).

Comment: I am trying to program a microcontroller without using any library, just by looking up on datasheet. I want to know how I can directly declare a variable that point to a specific register in a memory map. Please help me.

Comment: @Akhil, what do you mean what's the difference?  #1 just defines a constant integer, the second probably won't compile, and the third declares a pointer to a known address.  You probably want a `volatile` on #3 or you'll run into troubles.

Comment: When using the (3) one, i am wasting another RAM location to store the address of the location. Instead how can I directly point to a location? Is that #define method you mentioned above the only way??

Comment: @Akhil, Why does #3 have to go in RAM?  If you make it a local variable, it might only ever be in ROM or in a register.  But yes, it has to be *someplace*.

Comment: I am pretty noob at these stuff. The location that I am talking here is a register that controls a GPIO port of a microcontroller. Doesn't that reside in the RAM? My very limited knowledge is that, when I declare a pointer, a RAM location is reserved to store its target address location. I want to know if I can avoid reserving this location. Are you getting what I am trying to convey? Sorry if not. English is not my native language.

Comment: @Akhil, I think I understand what you're saying, but it seems like you're missing something pretty fundamental.  If you have a memory-mapped register you need to access, then yes, you need to have a pointer to that address someplace.  How else will the CPU know what to do?

Comment: okey.. tell me the difference between (1). #define newreg *((volatile unsigned long*)(GPIO_addr)) and (2). volatile unsigned *newreg = (unsigned long *)(GPIO_addr)... Is there any advantage when using (1) over (2)? I am coming from an electronics background. That's why I am missing these fundamentals. I checked lot of sources on web that discuss the Pointers, but none of them have what I need.

Comment: @Akhil, #1 isn't sufficient to do anything.  You'd need to combine with some kind of operator macro (like my `mmioReg` in the answer above).  The second one would work (except for your mismatched types) - you'd use it like `*newreg = writeValue` or `readValue = *newReg`.

Comment: @CarlNorum there is something wrong with my last comment. That's not what I wrote. Lots of 'stars' are missing. oops..

Comment: @CarlNorum okey.. tell me the difference between  (1). `#define newreg (*(volatile unsigned long *)(GPIO_addr))` and (2). `volatile unsigned long *newreg = (unsigned long *)(GPIO_addr)`... Is there any advantage when using (1) over (2)?

Comment: @Akhil - the first one has the dereference operator built in.  Otherwise they're the same.

Comment: My idea was the first one directly address a specific register and the second one reserves a space in RAM to store the address of the register thereby wasting RAM. I guess I was wrong.